# When I run the app, the layouts are ignored

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I tried adding constraints to a `UICollectionView` and a `UILabel` programmatically. Here is how I did it:

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[_labelToChange(30)]-0-[_datesCollectionView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_labelToChange, _datesCollectionView)]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[_labelToChange]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_labelToChange)]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[_datesCollectionView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_datesCollectionView)]];
```

When I run the app, the `constraints` are ignored, and I get the following error:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9daae70 H:|-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x7f96ca15a800]   (Names: '|':DIDatepicker:0x7f96c9d7f950 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9db6b00 h=--& v=--& UICollectionView:0x7f96ca15a800.midX == + 300>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9db6b50 h=--& v=--& H:[UICollectionView:0x7f96ca15a800(540)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9daae70 H:|-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x7f96ca15a800]   (Names: '|':DIDatepicker:0x7f96c9d7f950 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-06-04 13:58:14.692 myApp[581:8508] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9daaad0 H:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x7f96c9da8290]   (Names: '|':DIDatepicker:0x7f96c9d7f950 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9daab20 H:[UILabel:0x7f96c9da8290]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':DIDatepicker:0x7f96c9d7f950 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9daaef0 H:[UICollectionView:0x7f96ca15a800]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':DIDatepicker:0x7f96c9d7f950 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9db6b00 h=--& v=--& UICollectionView:0x7f96ca15a800.midX == + 300>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9db6b50 h=--& v=--& H:[UICollectionView:0x7f96ca15a800(540)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9db6e40 h=--& v=--& UILabel:0x7f96c9da8290.midX == + 300>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9daab20 H:[UILabel:0x7f96c9da8290]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':DIDatepicker:0x7f96c9d7f950 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-06-04 13:58:14.696 myApp[581:8508] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9daaad0 H:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x7f96c9da8290]   (Names: '|':DIDatepicker:0x7f96c9d7f950 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9db6e40 h=--& v=--& UILabel:0x7f96c9da8290.midX == + 300>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9db8960 h=--& v=--& H:[UILabel:0x7f96c9da8290(540)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9daaad0 H:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x7f96c9da8290]   (Names: '|':DIDatepicker:0x7f96c9d7f950 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-06-04 13:58:14.699 myApp[581:8508] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9d80160 H:|-(0)-[DIDatepicker:0x7f96c9d7f950]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f96c9d7f330 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9d80200 H:[DIDatepicker:0x7f96c9d7f950]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f96c9d7f330 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9daaef0 H:[UICollectionView:0x7f96ca15a800]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':DIDatepicker:0x7f96c9d7f950 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9db6b00 h=--& v=--& UICollectionView:0x7f96ca15a800.midX == + 300>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9db6b50 h=--& v=--& H:[UICollectionView:0x7f96ca15a800(540)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9db7dd0 'fittingSizeHTarget' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f96c9d7f330(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f96c9daaef0 H:[UICollectionView:0x7f96ca15a800]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':DIDatepicker:0x7f96c9d7f950 )>
```

Comment: have you tried to set `self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;`?

Comment: Just tried it. Same resluts

Comment: You should set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO for _labelToChange and datesCollectionView, not for self.

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks!! Just tried that, and it now works without the warning. But now, when I do `self.datesCollectionView selectItemAtIndexpath: animated: scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenterHorizontally`, it doesn't scroll?

Comment: That's a different problem. If you can't figure it out, you should post a new question.

Comment: create a separate question, do not mix up them all in one. @rdelmar, think you should post an answer :)

Comment: Thanks!! I posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655351/uicollectionview-is-not-scrolling. I would really appreciate it if you can answer!!

Comment: @rdelmar I'm not getting any answers to the link, what can I do?