# UICollectionView isn't scrolling to indexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` that I set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`, and added some `constraints`. When I try scrolling it to an `indexPath`:

```
[self.datesCollectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally];
```

Then it completely ignores that, and doesn't scroll. But when I remove `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`, then it scrolls, but the constraints are ignored.

My question is, How can I get the `collectionView` to scroll to an `indexPath` when `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is set to `NO`?

Comment: Does the cell get selected, or do you see no effect? How many cells do you have, and how many are on screen at one time?

Comment: The cells get selected, and when they get selected manually, they scroll to the center. I have about 365 `cells` all together. 6 `cells` are visible.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything special to get this to work. It works for me using your constraints (from your previous question). My test app to demonstrate this is here, http://jmp.sh/XmzrjzY

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! Here is a link to a project with the problem: http://jmp.sh/ZFJrPl7

Comment: That project you linked to does not contain a collection view.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right file?

Comment: Yeah, I had the right file, I just missed the collection view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your code, I found the problem. I'm not sure why this is the case, but the `contentSize` of the collection view was zero after applying the constraints. Adding a call to `layoutIfNeeded` to either `setSelectedDate:` or `setDates:` fixed the problem,

```
- (void)setDates:(NSArray *)dates {
    _dates = dates;
    [self.datesCollectionView layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.datesCollectionView reloadData];

    self.selectedDate = nil;
}
```